# vb.net - Can't generate the custom event

Tags: vb.net

I'm a little confused about the problem in this class. I want the Pay Button to generate a custom event. I am using Visual Basic Studio 2010 in .NET I think the main problem is within the RaiseEvent line.

```
    Public Class Payment
    Public Delegate Sub PaymentMadeEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PaymentMadeEventArgs)
    Public Event PaymentEvent As PaymentMadeEvent

    Private Property __paymentAmount As Decimal
    Public Property paymentAmount As Decimal
        Get
            Return __paymentAmount
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            __paymentAmount = value
            PaymentBox.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", __paymentAmount)
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub PayButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PayButton.Click
        RaiseEvent PaymentEvent(Me, New PaymentMadeEventArgs() {paymentSuccess = True})
    End Sub

    Public Class PaymentMadeEventArgs : Class EventArgs
            Private Property __paymentSuccess As Boolean
            Public Property paymentSuccess As Boolean
                Get
                    Return __paymentSuccess
                End Get
                Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
                    __paymentSuccess = value
                End Set
            End Property
        End Class
    End Class
End Class
```

Anyways, Advance thanks!

Comment: what is the error/unwanted behavior?

Comment: The system thinks the "paymentSuccess" variable is not declared

Comment: You used the wrong syntax for object initializing. Try `RaiseEvent PaymentEvent(Me, New PaymentMadeEventArgs() With {.paymentSuccess = True})`

Comment: now the error says that payment success is not a member of PaymentMadeEventArgs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors/bad coding styles in your code.

1. `Private Property __paymentAmount As Decimal`

You don´t need a private property, just use a variable. Also don´t use `__` as prefix. Use single `_` underscore or no prefix:

```
Private _paymentAmount As Decimal
```

2. `Public Property paymentAmount As Decimal`

Start public property names with a capital:

```
Public Property PaymentAmount As Decimal
```

3. `Public Class PaymentMadeEventArgs : Class EventArgs`

This is not the correct VB .NET syntax for inheritance.
Additionally use a Auto-Property for `PaymentSuccess` less code and better reading:

```
  Public Class PaymentMadeEventArgs
        Inherits EventArgs
        Public Property PaymentSuccess As Boolean

  End Class
```

After you fixed all of that raise your custom event in `PayButton_Click`:

```
RaiseEvent PaymentEvent(Me, New PaymentMadeEventArgs() With {.PaymentSuccess = True})
```

Comment: The inherits EventArgs line worked. I didn't knew this beforehand. My bad. Also will take note of these coding styles in the future. Thanks!